# How to simplify the function which finds homographs?

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, cycle

I wrote the function which finds homographs in a text.

> A homograph is a word that shares the same written form as another
>   word but has a different meaning.

For this I've used POS-Tagger from NLTK(pos_tag).

> POS-tagger processes a sequence of words, and attaches a part of
>   speech tag to each word.

For example:
*[('And', 'CC'), ('now', 'RB'), ('for', 'IN'), ('something', 'NN'),
('completely', 'RB'), ('different', 'JJ')].*

Code(Edited):

```
def find_homographs(text):
    homographs_dict = {}
    if isinstance(text, str):
        text = word_tokenize(text)
    tagged_tokens = pos_tag(text)
    for tag1 in tagged_tokens:
        for tag2 in tagged_tokens:
            try:
                if dict1[tag2] == tag1:
                    continue
            except KeyError:
                if tag1[0] == tag2[0] and tag1[1] != tag2[1]:
                    dict1[tag1] = tag2
    return homographs_dict
```

It works, But takes too much time, because I've used two cycles `for`. Please, advice me how can I simplify it and make much faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may seem counterintuitive, but you can easily collect *all* POS tags for each word in your text, then keep just the words that have multiple tags.

```
from collections import defaultdict
alltags = defaultdict(set)
for word, tag in tagged_tokens:
    alltags[word].add(tag)
homographs = dict((w, tags) for w, tags in alltags.items() if len(tags) > 1)
```

Note the two-variable loop; it's a lot handier than writing `tag1[0]` and `tag1[1]`. `defaultdict` (and `set`) you'll have to look up in the manual.

Your output format cannot handle words with three or more POS tags, so the dictionary `homographs` has words as keys and sets of POS tags as values.

And two more things I would advise: (1) convert all words to lower case to catch more "homographs"; and (2) `nltk.pos_tag()` expects to be called on one sentence at a time, so you'll get more correct tags if you `sent_tokenize()` your text and `word_tokenize()` and `pos_tag()` each sentence separately.

Comment: Wrong how? You're going to have to be more specific. I tested my code before posting, and it works correctly. Your output format cannot handle words with three or more POS tags, so my dictionary has words as keys and sets of POS tags as values.

Comment: alexis, it's my bad, I'm sorry. Your code works perfectly. Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion (not tested) but the main idea is to build a dictionary when parsing tagged_tokens, to identify homographs in non-nested loop:

```
temp_dict = dict()
for tag in tagged_tokens:
    temp_dict[tag[0]] = temp_dict.get(tag[0],list()).append(tag[1])
for temp in temp_dict.items():
    if len(temp[1]) == 1:
        del temp_dict[temp [0]]
print (temp_dict)
```

Comment: Laurent H., can't understand this 
`temp_dict.get(tag[0],list()).append(tag[1])`

Comment: Have you thought about what will happen if the _noun_ `cat` occurs three times?

Comment: Thank you, alexis. You are right, I haven't thought about that. I've fixed.

Comment: I don't see a fix (or any edit at all, for that matter).

Comment: @GiveItAwayNow, in fact my idea was the same as alexis' one. But alexis proposed a better code in his answer. The goal of temp_dict.get(tag[0],list()) is to get an empty list if the key tag[0] does not exist in the dictionary, otherwise it gets the value. Then the append method adds the tag to the value (which is a list).